# Asus UX501VW - System Eating CPU

Tags: windows-10, cpu, asus-laptop

Last few days I have a serious problem, my laptop suddenly started to eat CPU with the System process.
After a research I have found out its the ACPI Thread in it.
`HAL.DLL` is also linked in it by the chain in the process explorer, at the end of the chain.

I have found Process Hacker can help by Suspending ACPI, but I need a useful solution.

```
ACPI.sys+0x42f50
```

I've tried:

1. Reset
2. Reset with save nothing
3. Microsoft support
4. Changing drivers, all sort
5. Changing options/Resetting in Power - Plan Settings.

Answer (score 0):

FIGURED IT OUT
After long and frustrating searches for a solution.
I finally decided to dissasemble the laptop and check whats going on.

> Disassemble and clean from dust.

that's what fixed the issue, don't know what was wrong but it was finally FIXED.